# Windows Server Account locked - says need to use Remote Web Access

Tags: windows-server-2012, password, password-reset

Windows Server 2012 Essentials. I tried to log into the launchpad today and also the dashboard. Both give the following error: "The password for this user account has expired. To reset the password for this account, go to the Remote Web Access site and log on to the network."

I disabled Remote Web Access on this server a long while ago and have been able to log in since to update passwords when they expire. Something seems very fishy about this. I RDP'd to it and get a password invalid error. I hope I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Using another remote access tool (TeamViewer) I was able to just log in as normal and change my password. Would still like to know why this would be if anyone has ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Windows 2012 Essentials has NLA enabled for RDP sessions (which I believe is the default), then expired accounts would get an error when trying to RDP in with that password.  That's why they recommended using the RWA site to reset the expired password that way.

You can see more info from this blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2014/06/04/failed-logons-due-to-expired-passwords-password-change-functionality-in-rd-web-access.aspx

And you can see the issue with NLA enabled on RDP sessions and expired passwords here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2648397